# Как с помощью C# найти круглую, квадратную и треугольную форму на изображении?

Tags: c#

Как с помощью C# найти круглую, квадратную и треугольную форму на изображении?

На входе изображение, а на выходе выделяет эти формы на изображении

Comment: Желательно описать подробнее, в чём именно заключается вопрос, либо что именно не получается реализовать. В таком виде вопрос слишком общий, получение полезного ответа на него весьма маловероятно.

Comment: Дайте пример изображения

Comment: С такой формулировкой вопроса можно предложить только написать ИИ

Comment: Наверняка есть порт OpenCV под .NET. Выделяйте границы, а дальше вам придётся по границе определить, является ли она, к примеру, треугольником. Нет, готовой библиотеки для этого нету.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто в теории как реализовать... Есть 2 способа:

1. Используя нейронные сети искать соответствующие формы на картинке(обучить нейронную сеть их распознавать)
2. Слелать картинку монохромной и проанализовать все линии с резким перепадом контраста. Если несколько линий пересекаются-- проверить не является ли даная фигура одной из перечисленных. (проверять углы между точками пересечения и количество углов)

Готовое решение вам никто не напишет точно. Задача черезчур нетривииальная. Тем более, что спрашивается в довольно расплывчастой форме.